# Custom post-type for page header images

Tags: custom-post-types

I need some help getting a custom post-type for a banner image assigned to a page. There will only be one image per page and each page will have a different banner image that just needs to be output in an `img` tag.

I've tried this in my functions.php:

```
function sixohthree_init() {
    $labels = array(
        'name' => 'Header Images',
        'singular_name' => 'Header Image',
        'add_new_item' => 'Add Header Image',
        'edit_item' => 'Edit Header Image',
        'new_item' => 'New Header Image',
        'view_item' => 'View Header Image',
        'search_items' => 'Search Header Images',
        'not_found' => 'No Header Images found',
        'not_found_in_trash' => 'No Header Images found in Trash'
    );

    $args = array(
        'labels' => $labels,
        'public' => false,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'supports' => array('thumbnail')
    );

    register_post_type( 'header-image', $args );
}
add_action( 'init', 'sixohthree_init' );

/**
 * Modify which columns display when the admin views a list of header-image posts.
 */
function sixohthree_headerimage_posts_columns( $posts_columns ) {
    $tmp = array();

    foreach( $posts_columns as $key => $value ) {
        if( $key == 'title' ) {
            $tmp['header-image'] = 'Header Image';
        } else {
            $tmp[$key] = $value;
        }
    }

    return $tmp;
}
add_filter( 'manage_header-image_posts_columns', 'sixohthree_headerimage_posts_columns' );

/**
 * Custom column output when admin is view the header-image post list.
 */
function sixohthree_headerimage_custom_column( $column_name ) {
    global $post;

    if( $column_name == 'header-image' ) {
        echo "<a href='", get_edit_post_link( $post->ID ), "'>", get_the_post_thumbnail( $post->ID ), "</a>";
    }
}
add_action( 'manage_posts_custom_column', 'sixohthree_headerimage_custom_column' );

/**
 * Make the "Featured Image" metabox front and center when editing a header-image post.
 */
function sixohthree_headerimage_metaboxes( $post ) {
    global $wp_meta_boxes;

    remove_meta_box('postimagediv', 'header-image', 'side');
    add_meta_box('postimagediv', __('Featured Image'), 'post_thumbnail_meta_box', 'header-image', 'normal', 'high');
}
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes_header-image', 'sixohthree_headerimage_metaboxes' );

/**
 * Enable thumbnail support in the theme, and set the thumbnail size.
 */
function sixohthree_after_setup() {
    add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
    set_post_thumbnail_size(150, 100, true);
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'sixohthree_after_setup' );
```

The problem I have is I need to be able to assign a header image to a page or at least pull out a specific image per page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be very well achieved using [Advance Custom Field](https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/) (ACF) plugin. In your header image post type I suggest you also add support for title so that you can easily identify the header images in the listing. For that you just need to update

```
'supports' => array('title','thumbnail')
```

As for your main question of assigning one header image per page; once you install ACF plugin create a Field Group and a Field in that. Please refer below screenshot which will give you exact idea.

[image]

Then on 'Edit page' you will see a "Page Header Image" metabox as shown in below screenshot:

[image: Page header image meta box on edit page screen]

If you follow the settings as seen in first ACF screenshot then the above meta box will allow only one image per page. After all this is done, you can use following code to retrieve the header image assigned to a page:

```
  $page_header_img = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'page_header_image' ,true);
  echo get_the_post_thumbnail($page_header_img[0]);
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. Just trying this now, although so far I'm not seeing anything on the edit page screen appearing. How would this ACF know to link with a page?

Comment: I've managed to get that to appear on the page edit but I had to set a rule within ACF, so that `post is equal to page`. I'm having troubles getting this to output on the template though.

Comment: Yes you need a rule for a field group **Post Type is equal to page** If you look at last part of my answer, I have provided code how you can output the associated header image within a template. Please let me know if you tried that or not.

Comment: This worked a treat in the end. Sorry for slow acceptance of the answer. The only thing I've noted is that it's not working for the blog page for some reason?

Comment: Are you using a template for blog page? If so please make sure it contains the code I provided at the end of my answer. You may have to use conditional tag to detect the blog page, so please take a look at [this](https://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags#The_Blog_Page)

Comment: Thank you kindly I will take a look tonight. Appreciate all the help.

Comment: I am using a template yes. It just pulls in the header which is where the code is that looks for the custom banner field: ```<?php 
$image = get_field('page_header_image');
if( !empty($image) ): ?>
<img src="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image['alt']; ?>" />
<?php endif; ?>```

Comment: Further investigation looks like it might be due to setting the posts page. I think ACF might need some extra work around to access the field on this page.

Comment: Did you try codex help link I gave on 6th Oct? Please check that comment. The word "this" at the end of comment has link.